# could not convert string to float: 'YES' while using fit()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Trying to fit my model I get this error:

> could not convert string to float: 'YES'

Since I must have only numerical values I can guess that there is a string somewhere in my dataset.

This is the code:

```py
X_multi = df.drop('price', axis=1)
y_multi = df['price']
model1 = LinearRegression()
model1.fit(X_multi, y_multi)
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'YES'

This is `X_multi.info()` after making dummy variables:

```
Data columns (total 19 columns):
 #   Column                    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                    --------------  -----  
 0   crime_rate                506 non-null    float64
 1   resid_area                506 non-null    float64
 2   air_qual                  506 non-null    float64
 3   room_num                  506 non-null    float64
 4   age                       506 non-null    float64
 5   dist1                     506 non-null    float64
 6   dist2                     506 non-null    float64
 7   dist3                     506 non-null    float64
 8   dist4                     506 non-null    float64
 9   teachers                  506 non-null    float64
 10  poor_prop                 506 non-null    float64
 11  n_hos_beds                498 non-null    float64
 12  n_hot_rooms               506 non-null    float64
 13  rainfall                  506 non-null    int64  
 14  airport_YES               506 non-null    uint8  
 15  waterbody_Lake            506 non-null    uint8  
 16  waterbody_Lake and River  506 non-null    uint8  
 17  waterbody_River           506 non-null    uint8  
 18  bus_ter_YES               506 non-null    uint8  
dtypes: float64(13), int64(1), uint8(5)
```

This is `y_multi.head()`:

```
     crime_rate  resid_area  air_qual    room_num    age dist1   dist2   dist3   dist4   teachers    poor_prop   n_hos_beds  n_hot_rooms rainfall    airport_YES waterbody_Lake  waterbody_Lake and River    waterbody_River bus_ter_YES
0    0.00632 32.31   0.538   6.575   65.2    4.35    3.81    4.18    4.01    24.7    4.98    5.480   11.1920 23  1   0   0   1   1
1    0.02731 37.07   0.469   6.421   78.9    4.99    4.70    5.12    5.06    22.2    9.14    7.332   12.1728 42  0   1   0   0   1
2    0.02729 37.07   0.469   7.185   61.1    5.03    4.86    5.01    4.97    22.2    4.03    7.394   101.1200    38  0   0   0   0   1
3    0.03237 32.18   0.458   6.998   45.8    6.21    5.93    6.16    5.96    21.3    2.94    9.268   11.2672 45  1   1   0   0   1
4    0.06905 32.18   0.458   7.147   54.2    6.16    5.86    6.37    5.86    21.3    5.33    8.824   11.2896 55  0   1   0   0   1
```

It seems that `uint8` is the problem here, since everything is `float64`. How do I overcome this problem?

Also, `n_hos_beds` has missing values. This is the solution:

```py
df.n_hos_beds = df.n_hos_beds.fillna(df.n_hos_beds.mean())
```

Comment: n_hos_beds has missing values. this is the solution: df.n_hos_beds = df.n_hos_beds.fillna(df.n_hos_beds.mean())

Comment: Do not post comments with additional info. Amend your post with the additional code. In regards to your issue, I don't think a number type is the issue. The error states that it is trying to convert a string of `'YES'` to a float; not an integer.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, yes but I used dummy variables to remove all strings and set 0 or 1 as their values and n_hos_beds has missing values so when I filled it with mean value I didnt have the problem any more.

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback